Django random can't connect to mysql
In django I'm getting can't connect to mysql randomly
it works fine and just gives it to me and on refresh it works fine, completely random, I can't even reproduce it.
any ideas?
compose file:
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
          gateway: 172.16.238.1


services:
  web:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.6
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    image: project-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile.dev
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
      - ./backend/logs:/logs


  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./backend/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.9
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev_db
      MYSQL_USER: dev_db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root



You'll need to show us the exact error message.

can't connect to mysql server on 'db'
but sometimes I get lost connection to mysql server during query
I'm thinking it might be because of django silk, I'm removing it now and will keep testing

Look at the logs for the MySQL server running in the db container then.

Can't connect error message should have a number in parenthesis at the end that indicates the tcp error id. That should tell you what can't connect error exactly means. If the error is intermittent, then not sure what we can do about it with programming methods.

2002, can't connect to mysql on 'db' 115
